# Nextjs not reading cookie from Express response all in localhost

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, cookies, next.js

In my local environment, I'm trying to set up user tokens after login in my NextJS app (localhost:3005), using the response from my express backend (localhost:3020). I can see set-cookie in the response on the server, but the cookies in the `getServerSideProps` is empty always.

My code is pretty basic:

Express backend

```
 // Cors set up
 cors({
    methods: "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST",
    preflightContinue: false,
    credentials: true,
    origin: [
      "http://localhost:3005",
      ...
    ],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
  })

// Response - can see this cookie in set-cookie
return res.cookie("test", "test1", {
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: "none",
            expires,
            domain: "localhost:3005", // tried without this also
          }).redirect("http://localhost:3005/login");
```

My NextJS app has the following:

```
 //Login component : on login submit 
  const resp = await fetch(
      `${BACKEND_URL}login?originalUrl=/login`,  // Redirecting back
      {
        headers: new Headers({
          Authorization: "Bearer " + someToken,
        }),
        credentials: "include",
        method: "POST",
        redirect: "follow", // Tried this but did not work
      }
    );
   // resp.redirected is true

// Login component - triggers correctly but no cookies
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const { req } = ctx;
  const { cookies } = req;
  console.log("cookies", cookies );  // Always {}
  return { props: {} };
};
```

I have been stuck with this for a while now guys, it seems like I'm missing something very trivial here. I'm not super familiar with NextJs, so any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because of the Chrome SameSite=None + Secure requirement. Setting secure to true in the cookie resolved this issue. I did not have to set up SSL certificates for my local environment, just setting secure worked.